# a simple approach for paging and sorting in aspnetboilerplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

is there any  simple way for implementing paging in presentation layer in asp.net boilerplate solution like `PagedList` in `PagedList.Mvc` Nuget package.

I installed `PagedList.Mvc` package from Nuget gallery and change my Index method to this :

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page)
        {
            var pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1; //NewsService expects a 0 for the first page
            var pageSize = 3;
            int totalUserCount; // will be set by call to GetAllNews due to _out_ paramter :-|
            var newsResult = await _newsAppService.GetAllNews(new PagedResultRequestDto { MaxResultCount = pageSize });
            totalUserCount = newsResult.TotalCount;

            var news = newsResult.Items;
            var newsAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<NewsDto>(news, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, totalUserCount);

            ViewBag.OnePageOfNews = newsAsIPagedList;


            var model = new NewsListViewModel
            {
                News = news
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

and in View I add this under the news table :

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfNews, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

but when i click on number for example number 2 or 3 the table refresh but change data.

Comment: is it .net core application ?

Comment: @Saneeshkunjunni no it's asp.net mvc application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Boilerplate doesn't provide this, but it's simple to use `PagedList.Mvc` as you suggested.

It's easy to modify [`UsersController.Index`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/b5c18c989fa236d768d3ec6662edb5d66b4612c3/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L22-L32) to use [manual paging](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList#example-2-manual-paging):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page)
{
    var pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1;
    var pageSize = 10;
    int totalUserCount;

    var skipCount = pageIndex * pageSize;
    var pagedResult = await _userAppService.GetAll(new PagedResultRequestDto { MaxResultCount = pageSize, SkipCount = skipCount });
    totalUserCount = pagedResult.TotalCount;

    var users = pagedResult.Items;
    var usersAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<UserDto>(users, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, totalUserCount);

    ViewBag.OnePageOfUsers = usersAsIPagedList;

    // Code below unchanged
    var roles = (await _userAppService.GetRoles()).Items;
    var model = new UserListViewModel
    {
        Users = users,
        Roles = roles
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can in boilerplate application from presentation view if it is small then you can go with [bootstrap datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) if it is not then you can go with manual

For pagination you can use manual classes and list extension function

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
 public static PaginatedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, int page, int pageSize)
{
    int count = list.Count();
    var items = list.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, page, pageSize);
}
public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> ToAsycPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, int page, int pageSize)
{
    return await PaginatedList<T>.CreateAsync(list, page, pageSize);
}
}
```

and pagination class like this

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>// where T: IQueryable<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>
{
public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
public int RowCount { get; set; }
public int PageSize { get; set; }
public int FirstRowOnPage
{

    get { return (PageIndex - 1) * PageSize + 1; }
}
public int FirstPage
{

    get { return 1; }
}

public int LastRowOnPage
{
    get { return Math.Min(PageIndex * PageSize, RowCount); }
}
public int LastPage
{
    get { return (int)Math.Floor((decimal)RowCount / PageSize); }
}

public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    PageIndex = pageIndex;
    RowCount = count;
    PageSize = pageSize;
    TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
    this.AddRange(items);
}

public bool HasPreviousPage
{
    get
    {
        return (PageIndex > 1);
    }
}

public bool HasNextPage
{
    get
    {
        return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
    }
}

public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
}
```

after adding those two classes you can use this as

```
var data = await list.OrderBy(x => x.fieldname).ToAsycPagedList(page, pageSize);
var data = list.OrderBy(x => x.fieldname).ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
```